# ZFS nested datasets shown in KDE dolphin as mounted NFS shares. How to keep visible only parent mounted share?

Tags: nfs, zfs, dolphin

I have the ZFS pool called zdata on our server which is mounted at /mnt/zdata, and it is also shared with NFS, so clients can mount it.

The NFS share configured /etc/exports only for the parent dataset /mnt/zdata.
I didn't use zfs tools to configure NFS share, because it is easier to me to share only parent dataset this way. In other words, zfs sharenfs is OFF.

Share options are:

```
/mnt/zdata 192.168.0.0/24(sync,wdelay,hide,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,mountpoint,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,all_squash)
```

Pool contains lots of nested datasets which are also mounted, like these:

```
zdata/dataset01
zdata/dataset02
...
zdata/dataset10/subset01
zdata/dataset10/subset02
...
zdata/dataset99
```

The problem is that even when I have only /mnt/zdata shared on the server, and I mount it on the client, the nested datasets are also mounted as separate shares. And when I open the Dolphin in KDE, I get all shares in the left panel of dolphin in "Network Points". But I want to see only the parent share in that quick links.

In other words, I need to have access to the data in nested datasets, but I don't want to see all these quick links to each dataset except parent dataset in Dolphin.

I tried to share only parent dataset /mnt/zdata with sharenfs=on and set sharenfs=off on all the nested datasets. But the result is the same. Even if only the parent dataset is shared, when I mount it on the client, the nested datasets are also get mounted as separate mounts. That's why I see each of them in dolphin.

As I said I tried both 1) classic NFS share with /etc/exports method, 2) zfs set sharenfs=on method of sharing the parent dataset. But each of them gave me the same result.

Is there any way to share only the parent dataset, but keep access to the data in nested datasets. Or keep all datasets as separate mounts as right now, but not show them in Dolphin quick links on the left panel, because there are so many shares that they fill all the entire quick panel.